# Bug found in Optimal Number of Clusters algorithm - from de Prado and Lewis (2018)

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, correlation, machine-learning, cluster

I believe I have found a bug in Optimal Number of Clusters (ONC) from the paper "Detection of False Investment Strategies Using Unsupervised Learning Methods".

```
def clusterKMeansTop(corr0,maxNumClusters=10,n_init=10): 
  corr1,clstrs,silh=clusterKMeansBase(corr0,maxNumClusters=corr0.shape[1]-1,n_init=n_init) 
  clusterTstats={i:np.mean(silh[clstrs[i]])/np.std(silh[clstrs[i]]) for i in clstrs.keys()} 
  tStatMean=np.mean(clusterTstats.values()) 
  redoClusters=[i for i in clusterTstats.keys() if clusterTstats[i]<tStatMean] 
  if len(redoClusters)<=2: 
    return corr1,clstrs,silh 
  else: 
    keysRedo=[];map(keysRedo.extend,[clstrs[i] for i in redoClusters]) 
    corrTmp=corr0.loc[keysRedo,keysRedo] 
    meanRedoTstat=np.mean([clusterTstats[i] for i in redoClusters]) 
    corr2,clstrs2,silh2=clusterKMeansTop(corrTmp, \ 
      maxNumClusters=corrTmp.shape[1]-1,n_init=n_init) 
    # Make new outputs, if necessary 
    corrNew,clstrsNew,silhNew=makeNewOutputs(corr0, \ 
      {i:clstrs[i] for i in clstrs.keys() if i not in redoClusters},clstrs2) 
    newTstatMean=np.mean([np.mean(silhNew[clstrsNew[i]])/np.std(silhNew[clstrsNew[i]]) \ for i in 
    clstrsNew.keys()]) 
    if newTstatMean<=meanRedoTstat: 
      return corr1,clstrs,silh 
    else: 
      return corrNew,clstrsNew,silhNew
```

The line

```
if newTstatMean<=meanRedoTstat:
```

should be changed to:

```
if newTstatMean<=tStatMean:
```

and delete the line:

```
meanRedoTstat=np.mean([clusterTstats[i] for i in redoClusters])
```

otherwise the algorithm is comparing apples and oranges to maximize expected quality. Because `meanRedoTstat` is the expected quality of the below-average clusters while `newTstatMean` is the expected quality of above-average + the below-average re-clustered (with `kmeansBase()`) clusters. Hence `newTstatMean` is much more likely to be larger - even if reclustering under-performs current below-average clusters.

In the picture below is an example of the recursion on a 183 x 183 matrix where tstatMean=0.62 and is equal to the below clusters which are indicated with arrow. While tstatMean should be 1.07
[image: Bug in correlation matrix of 183 x 183]

Comment: I don't clearly see how we could be of help here. Maybe you could contact the authors?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would like some feedback - if you also see that that there is an error in the algorithm - or if im wrong. I have sent the author an email.

Comment: Hi @Endre: Sorry, I cannot give you any feedback on the algo.

Comment: Not entirely surprising: de Prado's oeuvre is largely a hall of smoke and mirrors.

Comment: BTW, there are like 5 different methods for fighting overfit given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00573), any of which seem like more promising candidates for the problem than some unsupervised clustering mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: This method is useful for finding signal in any correlation matrix that has eigen-values outside the marchenko-pastur distribution. Anything from time-series of stocks, time-series of fish-stocks estimation from catch and surveys, clustering of DNA sequencing data, and even weights-matrix in a convolutional neural network. If the eiven-values of your correlation matrix doesnt fit the marchenko-pastur distribution - you know its not a random matrix and you can start looking for signal in the matrix by looking for clusters.

Comment: If you are looking to find the number of significant dimensions for a dimensionality reduction, there is a whole body of literature on the topic. See, for example, the [PCDimension package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PCDimension/vignettes/PCDimension.pdf) and their references.